# restarting a Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes

I'm reading an article and having difficulty understanding some basic stochastic processes (I'm new to the subject so please pardon my wording of the question). Let $S$ be a set of states and $Q$ be a subset of $S$. Consider a Markov chain on $S$ and let's modify it to get a Markov chain on $Q$ as follows: if the Markov chain starts in $Q$, restart it uniformly in $Q$ whenever it exits $Q$. Let $A$ be the transition matrix of a Markov chain on $S$ and let $A_Q$ be the restriction of the transition matrix $A$ on $Q$. The article concluded that the **ergodic distribution** of the modified Markov chain is 
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{1}_Q\cdot (\boldsymbol{1}_Q+A_Q+A_Q^2+\dots)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,        (*)
\end{equation}
(in other words, the column sums of $(\boldsymbol{1}_Q-A_Q)^{-1}$).

My questions:

1. What does it mean to **restart a Markov chain uniformly**?
2. Is **ergodic distribution** the same as **stationary distribution** in this situation?
3. How to derive the formula $(*)$?

Thanks in advance!